# Why POST request to Java server (jax-rs, ejb) returns bad request(400) intermittently?

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs, ejb, openejb

I am using Jax RS in a Java application hosted on SAP NEO, and I am using @EJB annotation to create a field of a @Stateful service class, and when this field is used it gives exception mentioned below: (**this exception is intermittent, 90% times it works**)

```
EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException: Not Found javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: Not Found
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.convertException(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:429)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:351)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.methodCallUsingEJBField(Unknown Source)
```

(This is not complete stack trace)

call to method 'methodCallUsingEJBField(aTypeOfList)' is made inside method abc(String str)
and method abc is called by methodXYZ(MultipartBody body)

```
EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException: The transaction has been marked rollback only because the bean encountered a non-application exception :javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException : Not Found javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: The transaction has been marked rollback only because the bean encountered a non-application exception :javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException : Not Found
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.convertException(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:420)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:351)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy171.methodXYZ(Unknown Source)
```

Class definition

```
@Stateful
public class ServiceClasss implements InterfaceName
```

Field Declaration in dao

```
@EJB
private InterfaceName fieldName;
```

using the field in this way

```
 list = fieldName.methodCallUsingEJBField(list);
```

This exception is seen even if the session is active(at the time of using the application)(Was thinking about session timeout issue)

There is one another field annotated with @EJB in same dao class, it never throws exception(This EJB is of a @Stateless class)

Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
   <artifactId>apache-tomee</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Update:** The Dao class in which i am Declaring and using that EJB is Stateless

```
@Stateless
public class classNaameDao{
@EJB
private InterfaceName fieldName; //the class which implements this interface is @Stateful
//some code here
list = fieldName.methodCallUsingEJBField(list);
//using the field in this statelesss class
}
```

Any help is appereciated.

Comment: Stateful EJBs are bound to a session so I'd assume that either the session information is missing, the session has expired (and might have been renewed) or the EJB instance got removed. In general it's better not to use stateful EJBs for those reasons (among others).

Comment: Thank you for your response Thomas.
But my another concern is why it fails only in one of the class, i mean i have multiple Stateful classes and they have not failed yet, implementation is also the same but this exception is really painful for me.

Comment: Well, if it's only in this particular case there must be something different to the other cases. It might not be the actual implementation of the EJB but how it is used, e.g. when it is called, what other services are called in the same request, etc. - It's hard to remote debug that problem here so it will have to be you who analyzes it.